# Acumatica REST API Employee Record Creation issue, works for Update returns Internal Server Error 500

Tags: c#, acumatica

Following JSON in the Body of a PUT request will not create a record but will update a record if one already exists. Any insights as to why are greatly appreciated

Request returns Error 500 Internal Server Error. Internal Message is null.

Destination System is 2020R1 and NetFramework vs. 4.7.2
API Endpoint is Default 18.200.001

{"EmployeeID":{"value":"010"},"Status":{"value":"Inactive"},"EmployeeName":{"value":"Johnson, Samuel"},"Contact":{"FirstName":{"value":"Samuel"},"MiddleName":{"value":"D"},"LastName":{"value":"Johnson"},"Email":{"value":"sjohnson@some-eco.com"},"DateOfBirth":{"value":"1993-05-11T00:00:00"},"Address":{"AddressLine1":{"value":"961 Flora Dr."},"AddressLine2":{"value":null},"City":{"value":"Shreveport"},"Country":{"value":"US"},"State":{"value":"LA"},"PostalCode":{"value":"71106"}}},"EmployeeSettings":{"EmployeeRefNbr":{"value":"010"},"EmployeeClass":{"value":"STANDARD"},"BranchID":{"value":"AEL.ADMIN"},"DepartmentID":{"value":"ADMIN"},"Calendar":{"value":"STANDARD"},"LaborItem":{"value":"LABOR"}}}

Successfully Updated OK
Failed Created

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTfJP.png)

Comment: Figured this out, Contact should have read ContactInfo. The record was updating the non-contact fields but couldnt create because LastName is a required field and was not being seen in the JSON

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using the same json to create a new record there will be trouble ofcourse, because EmployeeId is a primary key and can not be inserted(you should check if your table has automatic identity increase) also check with your table constrains like (foreign keys).

if those were not the problem, please provide the code you are using.